# VPN messed up network connection

Tags: debian, wifi, vpn

I use Debian 11, recently I needed to connect to a VPN and run around some sites. Everything is fine - I installed Proton VPN, connected to the Netherlands and everything works. Then he retired from work for a time sufficient for the system to put the PC into standby mode. When I returned and returned the PC to its previous state, I was no longer connected to the vpn, this was indicated by the absence of the application in the processes and the status of the wi-fi connection in the taskbar and settings. But in reality, the Internet does not work, just sites or the same ping did not give results, but I can easily connect to the network. At the same time, if the module is disconnected from the PC, a cable connection icon appears instead of the wi-fi connection icon.

I checked everything that I thought might be causing this problem:

1. I checked that my gateway is registered in the routing table with the default route.
   Apart from him and one other related routes, ip route does not show anything more:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlxa0ab1beb5ed0 proto dhcp metric 600 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlxa0ab1beb5ed0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.35 metric 600
```

But as a result of the route command, there are several other routes, as I understood on the same device as my default gateway:

```
         target            gateway          source    proto    scope    dev tbl
/usr/bin/routel: 48: shift: can't shift that many
        default        192.168.1.1                     dhcp         wlxa0ab1beb5ed0 
   192.168.1.0/ 24                    192.168.1.35   kernel     linkwlxa0ab1beb5ed0 
      127.0.0.0          broadcast       127.0.0.1   kernel     link     lo local
     127.0.0.0/ 8            local       127.0.0.1   kernel     host     lo local
      127.0.0.1              local       127.0.0.1   kernel     host     lo local
127.255.255.255          broadcast       127.0.0.1   kernel     link     lo local
    192.168.1.0          broadcast    192.168.1.35   kernel     linkwlxa0ab1beb5ed0 local
   192.168.1.35              local    192.168.1.35   kernel     hostwlxa0ab1beb5ed0 local
  192.168.1.255          broadcast    192.168.1.35   kernel     linkwlxa0ab1beb5ed0 local
            ::1                                      kernel              lo 
fdeb:446c:912d:8da::/ 64                                   kernel         ipv6leakintrf0 
        fe80::/ 64                                   kernel         ipv6leakintrf0 
        fe80::/ 64                                   kernel         wlxa0ab1beb5ed0 
        default    fdeb:446c:912d:8da::1                   static         ipv6leakintrf0 
            ::1              local                   kernel              lo local
fdeb:446c:912d:8da::              local                   kernel         ipv6leakintrf0 local
fe80::638c:f26a:b64d:fd2e              local                   kernel         ipv6leakintrf0 local
fe80::811c:fb5a:a975:a2b3              local                   kernel         wlxa0ab1beb5ed0 local
```

2. The gateway is successfully pinged.
3. DNS servers are registered.
4. Tracing through my gateway is working, checked through traceroute.

Apparently everything should work, but something is still wrong.
Help to solve this problem, perhaps among the routes from routel there are connections that cause it?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you mean by "the Internet does not work, just sites or the same ping did not give results, but I can easily connect to the network".  Can you give an example of a command that does not work?  I'm not that familiar with the routel command, but it looks like it outputs the equivalent of "ip route show table all", which show routing entries, and not what I would call "connections".

Comment: DericS, thank for answer.
When I perform `ping google.com` i get an error similar to "google.com - not found".
Also I can't load any website, I get an error about internet connection.
But at the same time I see my network in the connection list

Comment: Although your "DNS servers are registered", it sounds like DNS is not working.  Your VPN software may have activated some firewall rules.  You could use "iptables-save -c" to get an idea if packet filtering is causing your problem.